# Three.js sets Texture RGB values to zero when ALPHA is zero on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, glsl, webgl

I am working on a WebGL project using javascript and the three.js framework. For that I am writing a custom shader with GLSL in which I have to load several lookup tables. Meaning I need to use some textures' individual RGBA values for some calculations rather than displaying them.

This works fine on all devices that I've tested. However, on iOS devices (like an iPad) the RGB values of a texture are automatically set to 0 when its alpha channel is 0. I do not think that this is due to GLSL's texture2D function but rather has something to do with how three.js loads textures on iOS. I am using the built-in TextureLoader for that:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var lutMap = textureLoader.load('path/to/lookup/table/img.png');
lutMap.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
lutMap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
lutMap.generateMipmaps = false;
lutMap.type = THREE.UnsignedByteType;
lutMap.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
```

For testing purposes I've created a test image with constant RGB values (255,0,0) and with a constantly decreasing alpha value from the top-right corner to the bottom-left one with some pixels' alpha values being 0:

[image: Test Image]

After the texture was loaded, I checked the zero-alpha pixels and their R values were indeed set to 0. I used the following code to read the image's data:

```
function getImageData( image ) {

    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );

    return context.getImageData( 0, 0, image.width, image.height );

}
```

The strange thing was that this was also true on my Windows PC, but the shader works just fine. So maybe this is only due to the canvas and has nothing to do with the actual problem. On the iOS device however, the texture2D(...) lookup in the GLSL code indeed returned (0,0,0,0) for exactly those pixels. (Please note that I come from Java/C++ and I am not very familiar with javascript yet! :) ) 
I've also tried to set the premultipliedAlpha flag to 0 in the WebGLRenderer instance, but also in the THREE.ShaderMaterial object itself. Sadly, It did not fix the problem.

Did anyone experience similar problems and knows how to fix this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: post your problem image on imgur?

Comment: I have updated the main post and added the test image.

Comment: Deleted my answer but the short of it was you can't use `getImageData` to check the contents of a texture because canvas uses premultiplied alpha so copying a texture through canvas 2D is lossy. As for the actual issue you pointed out there's a 2yr old bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165297 and I pointed out iOS fails the WebGL conformance tests https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/misc/gl-teximage.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0&quick=1 related to this issue

Answer (score 3):

The low level PNG reading code on iOS will go through CoreGraphics and premultiply each RGB value by the A component for each pixel, so if A = 0 then each RGB value will come out as zero. What you can do is load a 24 BPP image, so that the alpha is always 0xFF (aka 255), but you cannot disable this premultiply step under iOS when dealing with a 32 BPP image.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification! So there is no other method of loading (PNG) images on iOS? As already mentioned I am not quite familiar with JavaScipt and browser engines, yet.

Comment: Nope, no other method.